# How do I stop my character moving through objects with actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to flash and want to make it so when my character hits an object, they won't go through it, but still maintains control after they have hit it. I want it to be a solid object from all 4 points (top, left, right, bottom) of the object. Here is what I have been experimenting with...

```
   function hitsTheObject(e:Event)
{
    if (myCharacter.hitTestObject(Ball_mc))
    {
        gravity = 0
        hitObject = true
    }
    if (dIsDown == true && hitObject == true)

        myCharacter.x -=10
    }
```

The first if statement works, though the second one turns off the dIsDown button I have coded. Any thoughts?

Edit: Basically I want the character to hit an object and for it to block the character, as if it was a wall.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?  I'm not very clear on what you're trying to do or what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: Trying to make the character hit an object, so the character doesn't go through it, like a wall.

Comment: Have you tried using a physics engine?  It's abstracts this all out.    If rolling your own logic (if you want to learn),  you need stop your motion upon contact with the wall (but only for the direction the wall is in relation to your character)

Comment: What's a physics engine? I'm new to flash sorry

Comment: It's a kind of rule of Stack Overflow to first list the things you've tried to resolve your problem. If you don't know what a physics engine is - google it. If you haven't tried anything - try. We're not magicians, we can't write the code instead of you. Good luck!

Comment: You're all very useless at helping, thanks a lot guys, I recommend not using this site to "help" people. I ask for help and it's like "do it yourself", right yeah, thanks.

Comment: And by the way Andrey I did list the things I had tried, maybe you could learn to read "Here is what I have been experimenting with"

Answer (score 0):

Lewis, you're best bet is point collision. Here's some links to help you think it through and start off: http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/12/14/how-to-make-a-2d-platform-game-part-2-collision-detection/ and http://www.anotherearlymorning.com/2009/07/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in-actionscript-3/

Answer (score 0):

Check out my collision engine, it supports continuous/bullet collisions: https://github.com/Murplyx/AAE---Axis-Aligned-Engine